# Можно ли из c++ приложения отправить команду в консоль linux?

Tags: c++, linux

Можно ли из c++ приложения отправить команду в консоль linux?

Comment: Если Вы имеете в виду выполнить команду (например ls) и отправить ее вывод в stdout, то да, вызывайте функцию `system` (см. man 3 system).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно Вам подойдет вызов [system](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=system&category=3&russian=0).

Или нужно найти какую то конкретную открытую консоль и туда вставить команду?